# How to set a df column values based another df two columns values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, timestamp

I have two excel file. One with machine produced data with each row has a bunch os sensor data.

```
Time    S1  S2  S3

2019-01-04 05:00:20 -0,068576396    -0,081597209    0,328993082

2019-01-04 05:00:50 -0,071180522    -0,079861104    0,353298664

2019-01-04 05:01:20 -0,073784709    -0,081597209    0,391493082

...
```

The second has what is produced between two timestamp data:

```
From    To  product

2019-01-04 04:00:00 2019-01-09 08:00:00 T2887_001

2019-01-04 08:00:00 2019-01-09 12:15:00 T2887_002

2019-01-04 12:15:00 2019-01-09 14:00:00 T2887_003

...
```

There is no link between but the timestamps.

What I need:
In the first excel file I need an extra column. It values has to be the produced product number based on the second file start and end values.

To be honest I am very new with pandas but I read the basics and couldn't found my answer.

I load the excel in to df and save back. In the df when I check it all the necessary columns datatype is timestamp however when I saved as an excel and with openpyxl I load in python3 one of the column datatype is float.
I am not sure why.
What I try was to iterate over the two files to have my datas.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Szárítás összes januar_P.xlsx')
sheet_1 = wb['Sheet1']

wb_gy = openpyxl.load_workbook('Gyártások teszt_P.xlsx')
sheet_gy = wb['Sheet1']

s_gy = 2
while sheet_gy.cell(row=s_gy,column=1).value != None:
    s = 2

    while sheet_1.cell(row=s,column=1).value != None:

        if sheet_1.cell(row=s,column=2).value > sheet_gy.cell(row=s_gy,column=6).value and sheet_1.cell(row=s,column=2).value < sheet_gy.cell(row=s_gy,column=7).value :
            sheet_1.cell(row=s,column=16).value = sheet_gy.cell(row=s_gy,column=9).value

        s += 1

    s_gy += 1
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\p_jozsi\Desktop\Python\Dipa\Gyártás azonositok kiosztasa\gyartasok.py", line 15, in <module>
    if sheet_1.cell(row=s,column=2).value > sheet_gy.cell(row=s_gy,column=6).value and sheet_1.cell(row=s,column=2).value < sheet_gy.cell(row=s_gy,column=7).value :
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'float'
```

I would like something like this:

```
Time    S1  S2  S3  product

2019-01-04 05:00:20 -0,068576396    -0,081597209    0,328993082 T2887_001

2019-01-04 05:00:50 -0,071180522    -0,079861104    0,353298664 T2887_001

2019-01-04 05:01:20 -0,073784709    -0,081597209    0,391493082 T2887_001

...
```

I am really appreciate all the help.

Jozsef

Answer (score 0):

Use [`IntervalIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.from_arrays.html) and assign matched values of column `product`:

```
s = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2['From'], df2['To'], 'left')
#print (s)

df1['product'] = df2.set_index(s).loc[df1['Time'], 'product'].values
print (df1)
                 Time            S1            S2            S3    product
0 2019-01-04 05:00:20  -0,068576396  -0,081597209   0,328993082  T2887_001
1 2019-01-04 05:00:50  -0,071180522  -0,079861104   0,353298664  T2887_001
2 2019-01-04 05:01:20  -0,073784709  -0,081597209  0,3914930823  T2887_001
```

Comment: Dear jezrael,

First of all, Thank you for your answer!
When I tried it I get this error:
      File "C:\Users\p_jozsi\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 155, in set_axis
        'values have {new} elements'.format(old=old_len, new=new_len))
    ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 42330 elements, new values have 69 elements

Comment: Dear jezrael,
df1 hasn't got column 'Time'. Maybe I am wrong, but I think we need something else instead 'Time'

Comment: My bad, I was misspelled it.
But, When I corrected it, I got another error:

File "pandas\_libs\intervaltree.pxi", line 111, in pandas._libs.interval.IntervalTree.get_loc
KeyError: 1546578020000000000

Comment: Maybe I have the same issue, like this: 
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20636

Comment: @JózsefPeitli - What is your pandas version?